# Proving that angle measurement is well defined

Tags: euclidean-geometry, definition, triangles

[image]

In the figure, the angle $\theta$ is measured as $ \frac{s}{r}$. How do we know that the ratio is the same regardless of the choice of $r$ and the associated $s$?

Comment: https://www.math-only-math.com/s-is-equal-to-r-theta.html

Comment: What happens to $s$ when you double $r$?

Comment: The ratio is the same for similar polylines approximating $s$. And the length of $s$ is defined as the limiting length of such approximations.

Comment: @IAAW the link says the ratios of arcs are equal to the ratios of angles. How can I say that when I don't have a measurement of the angles yet?

Comment: @GReyes $s$ is proportionate to $r$ when the angle is constant, but this uses the definition itself and the question is about its validity.

Comment: Hint: think about how the circumference is defined in terms of the radius

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, oh, you mean that when the arcs are approximated by small straight lines that result from dividing the angle into many small angles, triangle similarity can be used to establish the equality of $\frac{"approximation" s_1}{r_1}$ and the same fraction for $r_2$ and $s_2$?

Comment: The proportionality of $r$ and $s$ makes the definition meaningful. That is, independent of the choice of the radius, of the units you use etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That result holds for any polyline, hence for their limit.